# Boost Graph classes not recognized

Tags: catkin, boost, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Boost Graph on my node, but when I declare an object from Boost Graph I get these errors:

> error: ‘adjacency_list’ does not name a type

> error: ‘graph_traits’ does not name a type

Then I followed the instructions from [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) to properly include the boost  during compilation, but the error persists.

I'm sure that Boost Graph is installed and it's working, because I have compiled a similar code using Boost Graph which does not use ROS, so I think that the error stills in the CMakeLists.txt file. Other objects from Boost seem to work fine, like mpl::vector.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(prm_nav)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread graph)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  map_server
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  tf
)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES prm_nav
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs map_server nav_msgs roscpp tf
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(prm src/prm.cpp)    

target_link_libraries(prm
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}   
)
```

So, what is the correct way to use Boost Graph inside ROS? Am I missing something in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Thanks a lot,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198671/boost-graph-classes-not-recognized/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this is a bug in your code and not in your build files, because you're getting an error about missing types/symbols/namespaces. If this was an error in your build files, I would expect either missing header files or linker errors about undefined symbols.

I suspect this is as simple as missing the boost namespace on these keywords, or missing a `using namespace ...` clause, but without seeing a sample of what you're trying to compile, it's hard to say for sure.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2014-12-01**:
I missed the  "using namespace boost;" line, exactly what you said! Thanks a lot!